# What serves the same purpose of Java volatile in C++?

Tags: java, c++, caching, volatile

I learned the `volatile` keyword in Java. It serves as a mean to ensure visibility in other threads when a variable is written by one particular thread. It does this by removing machine caches of certain variables and disabling CPU instruction reordering under some cases at each write.

I noted that `volatile` exists in C++, while it serves different purposes. I wonder how C++ implements cache coherence and other things that goes with `volatile` in Java.

Comment: I don't believe C++ has a equivalent in the language.  Traditionally the C family of languages has used external libraries for this.  I think C++ has a `threads` library as part of the standard library now which has these functions

Comment: Doesn't `volatile` in `C++` have similar (if not the same meaning) that [memory accesses cannot be optimised out via caches or similar and side effects cannot be reordered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)? If you want something that avoids UB while getting modified by multiple threads maybe [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)?

Comment: There's no cache coherence or whatnot. There's data races and there's atomics. `volatile` in Java is atomics. `std::atomic` in C++ is atomics.

Comment: Does atomics in C++ ensures write visibility and cache coherence？ I suppose I should wrap everything with atomics.

Comment: Read about data races. You're conflating hardware and language concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Modern mainstream CPUs have coherent caches. That is taken care of by the cache coherence protocol. This is independent if a field is (Java) volatile or not. So there is also coherence on plain loads/stores. Although it can be that higher up the chain coherence is violated.

The C++ version of Java volatile would be an atomic with memory_order_seq_cst (which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement.

C++11 derives its memory model from Java, but it explicitly acknowledged that some Java choices turned out to be suboptimal. Java's `volatile` semantics are one of those, as was the ability to synchronize on every object.

C++ does *not* implement cache coherence. That's something for compilers and CPU's. At the C++ level, you have ordered operations. A *happens-before* B. One such case, that could be compared with `volatile` in some sense, are C++ atomics.